Load balancing by nginx between 3 servers with Symfony and React and Docker programming languages
I have 3 servers with different IPs.
It has been implemented on 2 application servers using Symfony and React based on Docker.
I want to install nginx on the last server and do load balancing between 2 Symfony servers.
Can anyone help?
load balancing with nginx

This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/61926700/5598917
additionally it will be easier to get help if you state what you have tried.
